# Как выполнить действие при столкновении игрока с объектом только один раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

Написал функцию обработки столкновения игрока с объектом, используя модуль pygame:

```
def collide(self, xvel, yvel, plantlist):

    for sprite in plantlist:
      if collide_rect(self, sprite):
        if isinstance(sprite, sunPlants):                       
            print("sun")

        if isinstance(sprite, shadowPlants):
            print("shadow")

        if isinstance(sprite, waterPlants):
            print("water")
```

Но есть проблема. Функция выполняет нужное условие бесконечно, пока игрок не отойдёт от объекта. А мне нужно, чтобы оно (условие) выполнилась только один раз и в следующий раз, только после того как игрок вновь "столкнётся" с объектом.

Полный исходный код игры можно найти [на GitHub.](https://github.com/DeepDagon/ExtraAlchemy)

Comment: У вас в гитхаб репозитории в файлике Как играть.txt допущена ошибка в 1-ой строке. Вместо М(L) должно быть Д(L) или М(V)

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения ООП, лучше всего может быть хранить в игроке список объектов с которыми сейчас есть контакт. При добавлении нового элемента в список, выполнять событие начала контакта, а при удалении объекта из списка - окончание контакта.